# Hibernate insert in catch block

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Jax-Rs web service and hibernate. I am doing an insert, and if that insert fails, I should catch the exception and write a log in the database. Here is the code below

```
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
   private EntityManager em;

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/siminsert")      
   public String testSimInsert()
   {
       try
       {
          Query query = em.createNativeQuery("insert into sim(iccid, imsi, msisdn, state) values ('890000000000010000512223334', '001010000100004', '50100005', 'A')");
          query.executeUpdate();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {           
           Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery("insert into notifications(message) values ('An error occured')");
           query1.executeUpdate();

       }

      return "OK";
      }
```

With this code, the first insert will fail since we are inserting more than allowed characters in the iccid field. I want to be able to log that error by doing an insert in the notifications table as shown in the code but i get the error:

```
  javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Any ideas on what can be done?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception doesnt comes from the first query?

Comment: No. The first query generates a javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Comment: One general thing: is it a good architecture to log such errors within a database? Maybe a flat file would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you don't open a Transaction and this is mandatory for DML operations (UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE):

Whenever a Hibernate Session operation throws an exception you have to discard the current Session and start anew. This is because the failing operation might have left the Session in an inconsistent state.

What you can do is to discard all changes:

```
em.clear();
```

and run your second query. Make sure you operate with 2 transactions. If one fails you start with a new one to insert into the notification table.

```
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("insert into sim(iccid, imsi, msisdn, state) values ('890000000000010000512223334', '001010000100004', '50100005', 'A')");
    query.executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();      
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    if(tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
        em.clear();
        try {               
            tx.begin();            
            Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery("insert into notifications(message) values ('An error occured')");
            query1.executeUpdate();
            tx.commit();
        } catch(Exception ex) { 
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }   
}
finally {
    em.close();
}
```

A better approach is to have all the business logic encapsulated in @Transactional services. So you have a :

1. SimService.insert(Sim sim);
2. NotificationService.error(ErrorMessage message);

Both methods are @Transactional so if the first one fails with an exception, your controller can call the NotificationService.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Same exception mate. javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query, but now for query1.

Comment: You didn't use transactions at all. Check my updated example.

Comment: @Vlad Is it necessary to use 'try'twice?

Comment: @Atul In fact not only that we can use only one try, but we can also use one EntityTransaction reference, since getTransaction always returns the same object.

Comment: Correct and thanks for modifying the code. I think earlier code would have confused some people.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the transaction handling.  Although it is not visible from your code,  to insert the sim record,  you need to begin a transaction.  Now since an error has occurred,  this transaction will rollback. You need to write your log statement in a separate transaction.  So in the catch block,  you need to starta new transaction,  write the log and commit the transaction, without touching the transaction state of the previous transaction.  Hence you cannot use the same hibernate session.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as other answers have pointed, please use transactions, rollback, etc.
For better understanding, do read about [Container Managed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) transactions and [bean managed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) transactions. Vald's code should help.

On side notes,

1. You should use finally block to clean up resources, which you seem to missing.
2. You seem to use @GET for inserting data. I assume that you have just written this for convenience of this SO question. If not, a brief intro to REST and HTTP methods should help.
3. For better understanding and maintenance of this code a couple of years down the line, I would suggest that you separate 'normal insert' and 'exceptional insert' statements in maybe two different methods/places. As such in both scenarios you seem to be returning "OK". And probably it would be better to separate them (normal and exceptional scenarios) if they are located in different places.